My laptop is showing full charging when plugged in but when I plugged off , my laptop just shut down
I first thought my battery is broken so I replaced it but it's still showing the issue , My battery is full charged but still my laptop doesn't turn on when I plugged in it will then turn on idk what is the issue pls help me

If you got a third party battery, it could also be the "new" battery is already dead.

This is a sign that your battery is at the end of its life.
As your battery ages, its capacity gets smaller, accepting less and less charge.  Ultimately, its capacity will be too small to power your laptop for a useful amount of time.  It sounds like this has happened.
A number of factors affect how your battery ages, including time since manufacture (obvious), number of charge cycles, deepness of charge cycles, and how long it has been left uncharged.   If you want to know more about this, including what you can do to extend the life of a (new) battery, see batteryuniversity.com

OP writes that he replaced the battery ... so it is probably not warn out because of age.
